# controlgroup button issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I wanted something like in this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WfaF.jpg) (text btn and arrow btn of same height). But I couldn't get it. Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but something like: http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/10/ ?  Does it need to be a second button?

If so, you can probably fake it with a non-breaking space if you don't want to get too messy with the css.  http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/13/

Comment: T. Sage -- thanks..I'm trying to mimic exactly as in the image..is there a way that I can reduce the width of the second button (that contains arrow)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah same as J.T.Sage, why the two buttons?

My failed attempts: http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/38/

```
<div data-role="page" id="button-tests">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="tel:(866) 444-8619"  data-role="button" data-theme="e">Call (866) 444-8619</a>
        <a href=""  data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="tel:(866) 444-8619"  data-role="button" data-theme="e">Call (866) 444-8619</a>
        <a href=""  data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" style="height:100%;" class="fix-button-height" id="custom-button-height"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="tel:18664448619"  data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="right">Call (866) 444-8619</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="tel:(866) 444-8619"  data-role="button" data-theme="e">Call (866) 444-8619</a>
        <a href=""  data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="arrow-l" class="hide-text" data-iconpos="right">|</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fix-button-height .ui-icon {
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    display:block;
}

.hide-text {
    color:#fceda7;
}

.hide-text:hover { 
    color:#faeb9e;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PtLKF/39/ - got the css to work, at least on my display - however, if the text size is slightly different on yours, it will look wrong again.

Comment: @J.T. Sage -- thanks..I'm trying to mimic exactly as in the image..is there a way that I can reduce the width of the second button (that contains arrow) – Priya